# C# TimeSpan Not Displaying Days

Tags: c#, formatting, timespan

I am writing an app that uses the `TimeSpan` object.  Specifically I am using the constructor `TimeSpan(int32, int32, int32, int32)`.  However, when I output my results to an Excel file the TimeSpans display in the format `hh:mm:ss` where I was expecting `dd:hh:mm:ss`.  With the data I have right now all of the days are `0` -- but then I was expecting `00:hh:mm:ss` instead of the shorter format.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: How do you output the results to excel, I'm guessing the problem is there, not in the constructor you call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the formatting of the cells in Excel to the format you want. It probably set the formatting automatically because all the day values are 0

Comment: I'm outputting the TimeSpans to strings and the Excel column is formatted for strings.

Comment: If you are using TimeSpan.ToString() then that's the problem. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx it says ToString() outputs in the format: [-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]  and goes on to state that elements in [] may not be included. Use one of the ToString methods that allow you to specify a format string